# How to remove Mono?

Tags: mono

How do I remove Mono from my Ubuntu installation?

Which applications depend on Mono? Could you suggest me some alternatives?

Comment: why do you want to remove Mono?

Comment: Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### 10.04

**First Things First**: The list of applications that will be removed if you remove Mono:

- Tomboy
- gBrainy (I'm not sure if an alternative exists)
- Docky
- Gnome Do
- Banshee
- F-Spot

---

**Alternative Applications**:

- **Tomboy alternative**:

  [GNote](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnote) [image: Install gnote]: `sudo apt-get install gnote`
- **Docky alternatives**:

  [Avant Window Navigator](http://packages.ubuntu.com/avant-window-navigator) [image: Install avant-window-navigator]: `sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator`

  [Cairo Dock](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cairo-dock) [image: Install cairo-dock]: `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock`
- **Gnome Do alternative**:

  [Kupfer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kupfer) [image: Install kupfer]: `sudo apt-get install kupfer`
- **Banshee alternatives**:

  Clementine Music Player: http://www.clementine-player.org/

  [Rhythmbox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/rhythmbox) [image: Install rhythmbox]: `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

  [Exaile](http://packages.ubuntu.com/exaile) [image: Install exaile]: `sudo apt-get install exaile`

  [Amarok](http://packages.ubuntu.com/amarok) [image: Install amarok](KDE application): `sudo apt-get install amarok`
- **F-Spot alternatives**:

  [Shotwell](http://packages.ubuntu.com/shotwell) [image: Install shotwell]: `sudo apt-get install shotwell`

  [Digikam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/digikam) [image: Install digikam](KDE application): `sudo apt-get install digikam`

---

**Mono Removal**:

1. Make a backup of all your data associated with Mono applications.
2. `sudo apt-get purge libmono* libgdiplus cli-common libglitz-glx1 libglitz1`

Comment: +1. Maybe it's worth mentioning, that only Tomboy and gbrainy are installed by default (+Banshee in Ubuntu 11.04).

Comment: Basket is a nice KDE-replacement for Tomboy

Comment: `mono-runtime` is the base package. Uninstall it and all the dependent packages will be removed

Comment: Ouch! Synaptic shows that Pinta requires mono.

Comment: @fossfreedom Any suggestions about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35031150/2404470)

Answer (score 17):

### 12.04

For Ubuntu 12.04 if you want to remove the complete mono packages you need to remove `mono-runtime`

```
sudo apt-get purge mono-runtime
```

This is the base package and should recursively remove all packages which need it

Comment: I'm getting this errors on Ubuntu Saucy: http://askubuntu.com/q/382298/62483

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.1.