# Will mono be carried forward by upgrading to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, uninstall, mono

I plan to **upgrade** from 11.10 to 12.04 when 12.04 is released.
I noticed from my previous experience in upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10, that Synaptic, which was dropped in 11.10, was retained on my system presumably because I upgraded from 11.04 (which did have Synaptic by default) and didn't do a new install.

Given that Synaptic was retained, my question relates to **mono**. If I don't remove mono, will it be carried forward when I upgrade to 12.04 just like Synaptic was?

Edit:
Updated information on programs that need mono and how to remove it are here: [How to remove Mono?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12897/how-to-remove-mono).

Comment: The 2nd part of your question is a duplicate, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12897/how-to-remove-mono

Comment: I cited that reference. It is was from 2010.

Comment: I like the question because you've obviously been thinking about what you want and what consequences it might bring. I don't know the answer to your question. But if I would want to find it out myself I'd create a virtual machine inside VirtualBox and started to check it. Anyways, lot of 12.04 experience here the last couple of days so you might get lucky today :o)

Comment: @vasa I've put a bounty on it to update it.

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is installed, it will generally be upgraded to the new version when doing an upgrade. If it's installed and nothing is using it, it may be recommended for removal during the upgrade. The upgrade process will present a list of packages which may be removed if they are no longer needed or supported. When this happens, you will also be given the option to keep or remove those packages. Such should be the case with mono here.

Comment: Then I will let the upgrade process suggest its removal (or not). That seems the safer course.

Comment: I was wondering why my webserver had no blog spam since a couple of months. Turned out that Ubuntu server dropped b2evolution somewhere along the line. The software was uninstalled during patching without me knowing/realizing it ... What I'm trying to say, don't always count on what 'generally will happen'

Comment: Fair enough. But let's give the upgrade process the benefit of doubt. As for your other suggestion about VirtualBox, I'm not confident about setting it up since I'm relatively new to all this.