# E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, glib

I've been trying to install the CoreBird Twitter application and have had horrible luck with getting it to compile and then I came across a deb (from [here](http://edwardbetts.com/corebird/)) and tried to install it that way.

However, I got this error:

```
 corebird depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 corebird depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.13.7); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-0:amd64 on system is 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4.
```

So, I tried to be smart and manually track down and install those libraries. I found the correct deb file, but when I ran `dpkg -i` for the `libglib` deb, I got this:

```
pkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:amd64 (--install):
 package libglib2.0-0:amd64 2.42.0-2 cannot be configured because libglib2.0-0:i386 is at a different version (2.40.2-0ubuntu1)
```

and something else about not being able to configure it because libglib2.0-0:amd64 was the wrong version.

This is where I went wrong. I, without thinking, ran `sudo apt-get remove libglib2.0-0:amd64`.

So, obviously, it created a crap ton of dependency issues and told me to run `sudo apt-get -f install`. I did that, and now I get this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 corebird : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.13.7) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4 is installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.42.0-2) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.42.0-2 is installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.42.0-2 is installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.42.0-2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Apparently, the `glib` 2.42.0-2 package installed after I removed the previously installed 2.40.2, and is now causing all sorts of issues. Obviously, this is an issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

My `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` file is empty:

```
cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
cat: /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log: No such file or directory
```

and the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns nothing:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
$
```

**EDIT**

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382298/e-error-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-while-uninstalling-mono) is not a duplicate. I can't install `aptitude` even if I wanted to (same error.)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do it like that:

```
sudo apt-get remove corebird
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then make sure that everything is back to normal.

After that, change repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `vivid` and get the needed libraries through apt-get.

Install `corebird` with dpkg.

Change `/etc/apt/sources.list` back to `trusty`.

Comment: doesn't work if corebird is the dependency of some system package

Answer (score 1):

I know your are looking for a general issue, but I stumbled upon this for the corebird app.  You now have an easier option on 16.04+ to use corebird:

```
sudo snap install corebird
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with the terminal, I randomly came out with a solution, it is as follows :-

Install Synaptic Package Manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Now go to the Synaptic package manager through the start or by typing `sudo synaptic` on the terminal

Next, search for the package with unmet dependencies.

Mark the package for `complete removal`

Click `Apply` at the top

Synaptic will first resolve the unmet dependencies and then it will completely remove the package, you can install it again later.

Just try it, it should work to the best of my knowledge. In my case, it did work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your corebird index

```
praz@Lenovo-E10-30:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi corebird_1.0-1_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

Modern, easy and fun Twitter client
 Twitter client, built using GTK+.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package corebird.
(Reading database ... 273217 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack corebird_1.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking corebird (1.0-1) ...
Setting up corebird (1.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1.17.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.10.20170810-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.17.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.54.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.54.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
```

after installed I can open it

[image: my corebird have been opened]

I think try use gdebi, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am with same solution as https://askubuntu.com/a/634356/26246 answer here to remove `corebird` , and reverse `libglib2.0-0` to same version for both architectures `amd64` & `i386` . Check using `apt-cache` for available versions.

It is seems that corebird package was prepared for specific Ubuntu release (older one), for clean install better to go with snap , [flatpak](https://corebird.baedert.org/)(Official) or `chroot` solutions. Also posible to rebuild Debian package as the source package was provided in the repository mentioned in the question.